# Tengo un un problema con un array y una función Observable (Angular y Firebase)

Tags: angular, firebase, promesas, callback

Estoy recorriendo un array con foreach para sacar un id de cada elemento y pasarlo a una funcion observable que me va traer los datos de ese objecto pero no me esta funcionando el forech no espera respuesta de la funcion y por ende me manda un undefined de respuesta como debo hacer para solucionar este problema ya que e utilizado la funcion con solo un id y funciona, creo que debo utilizar un tipo de promesa o algo por el estilo pero no se como hacerlo ya que soy nuevo en estas tecnologías.

Asi esta mi codigo

```html
encontrarPersona(){
    /* El array contiene datos entre ellos el id */  this.imagenes.forEach( element => {
      console.log("d");
    /* Esta funcion va a firebase a buscar los datos  */  this.servicioImagen.findPersonaDB(element.id_persona).subscribe(data =>{
        console.log(data.payload.data());
      });
  });

}
```

Y al correr el codigo muestra el console.log(d) las veces que se recorre el array y al final los undefined de cada busqueda.

**En poco resumen tengo un array con unas id que necesito pasarlas a una Api y para eso utilizo un foreach, la cuestion es que el foreach no espera la repuesta de la API sino que se recorre y se termina en si.**

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: En poco resumen tengo un array con unas id que necesito pasarlas a una Api y para eso utilizo un foreach, la cuestion es que el foreach no espera la repuesta de la API sino que se recorre y se termina en si. @Comunidad

Comment: Puedes utilizar una promesa, de manera que se espere la resolución o el rechazo de la petición para continuar con el código.
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-promise-tutorial-how-to-resolve-or-reject-promises-in-js/
Se requiere más detalle para poder ayudarte con una solución específica.